# jQuery bxSlider and jQuery-ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs, bxslider

I am using jQuery-ui for it's tab feature and also using bxSlider to slide images/content within only the first tab. However, when I click on the second tab the bxSlider "prev" and "next" options are still in my container. I tried using `event.stopPropagation()`, `event.preventDefault()` and `stop()` to stop the function, after realizing those didn't work I tried to create a function like this:

```
(function() {
    $('#ab').click(function() {
        $('#showcase').bxSlider({
            controls: false,
        });
    });
});
```

where '#ab' is the tab and #showcase is the list element the images are located in. This function wouldn't exactly stop the bxSlider from being active, it would simply just hide the controls. However this did not work either.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="sh" href="#showcase">Resumes</a></li>
            <li><a id="ab" href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="showcase_container">
            <ul id="showcase">
                <li>
                    <a href="resume-purchase.php"><img src="images/resume-temp1.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="resume-purchase.php"><img src="images/resume-temp2.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="resume-purchase.php"><img src="images/resume-temp3.jpg"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/resume-temp1.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/resume-temp2.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/resume-temp3.jpg"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="about">
                <span class="ab_title">Portfolio</span>
                    <ul id="portfolio_list">
                        <li class="item">
                            <a class="caption" name="resume1" href="#">
                                <img src="images/ty-headshot.jpg">
                                <span>
                                    <big>Portfolio Title</big>
                                    Quick Description of Portfolio Item
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a class="caption" name="resume1" href="#">
                                <img src="images/ty-headshot.jpg">
                                <span>
                                    <big>Portfolio Title</big>
                                    Quick Description of Portfolio Item
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item">
                            <a class="caption" name="resume1" href="#">
                                <img src="images/ty-headshot.jpg">
                                <span>
                                    <big>Portfolio Title</big>
                                    Quick Description of Portfolio Item
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
    //initialize tabs
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});

//initialize slider
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showcase').bxSlider({
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        infiniteLoop: false,
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If this cannot be done can someone please redirect me to a similar image/content slider so I can make this work?

Comment: Do you have a test link that you could show so we can see whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the ul tag used for the slider in another div (called showcaseTab) or whatever. The bxslider will then be contained to that tab and the arrows should show and hide the correct way.

```
<div id="showcaseTab">
 <ul id="showcase">
            <li>
                <a href="resume-purchase.php"><img src="images/resume-temp1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="resume-purchase.php"><img src="images/resume-temp2.jpg"></a>
                <a href="resume-purchase.php"><img src="images/resume-temp3.jpg"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/resume-temp1.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/resume-temp2.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="images/resume-temp3.jpg"></a>
            </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, however this did not work. I had tried this previously and it didn't work, but I also tried your code and I got the same issue.

Comment: have you got the solution? i am stuck into similar situation. post the answer if you have found solution.  Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming the arrows/controls are absolutely positioned? I'd suggest not using the defualt controls from bxSlider and creating custom ones using bxSlider's methods. That way you can contain the arrows inside the showcase ul. See here: http://bxslider.com/options and look for "goToNextSlide" and "goToPrevSlide"